# Align two divs side by side covering entire page width

Tags: html, css

I have simething like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        (an image)
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        (some divs and other text)
    </div>
</div>
```

and I want toalign the 2 divs side by side

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.left, .right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

What do I need to do, because this doesn't work

Comment: We can assume that your code doesn't work from the fact that you're asking a question at all; but "*this doesn't work*" tells us nothing about the way in which it doesn't work, what does your code not do? What should it do? What does it do instead?

Comment: Well, since they already does that, being side-by-side covering entire page width, what is it that does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No have problem with your code... Divs are aligned side by side...

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    (an image)
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    (some divs and other text)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope (do that with a comment, as I did), answer is suppose to fix something that does not work, the one's that work we close as _a problem that can no longer be reproduced_ as there is no problem

Comment: the problem was that I had the img set to 50% and the contents of the right div set to 50%. it should have been 100% and the containser at 50%, it used the same space but now they are aligned properly.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you want to do full-height divs with half screen spreading. this will work.

```
.Left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
  background-color:black;

}

.Right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0; 
  background-color:blue;
}
```

### Here's an working [Example.](https://codepen.io/jaydevs/pen/KmpPKP)

Comment: It is not asked for height, it is asked for width, which works already, so no need to post answer for something that is working

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have given padding, margin, border to child div 
it should work
try this

decrease some width of child div 
50% to 49% like this or

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
.left, .right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
```

Comment: The given code is working already, so why post an answer?? ... Asking about paddings and margin is supposed to be done using a comment, but since you haven't enough reps. to do that, be patient and answer question that does not need clarifications until you do